# Interpreting functions with callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've come across a piece of code and rather than just copying it and pasting it, I'd like to understand how it is it actually works.

Most basic tutorials don't seem to address the syntax of callback functions (or I just don't understand them). The example I have is something from passportjs

```
passport.use(new Strategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));
```

What I want to know is if 'cb' is a parameter for the function, what does return cb(null, user) actually mean in this context? Does it mean execute a callback function with parameters null and user (which doesn't make sense to me).

Comment: "Does it mean execute a callback function with parameters null and user (which doesn't make sense to me)." — Yes. What doesn't make sense about that?

Comment: If that function is not defined elsewhere - how is a function called "callback" being executed? And more pertinently what is the result of a function that doesn't have any instructions associated with it?

Comment: Need explanation of concept, which is not the purpose here. I will suggest have some book or any reference and read about the things which doesn't make sense to you likewise- JavaScript in this case.

Comment: It is defined elsewhere. It is passed to the anonymous function as an argument when that function is called. You can see that on line 2 of your code.

Comment: @tichy255 Functions are first class members in JavaScript, so they can be assigned to variables, passed as parameters of other functions and returned from functions, too. That's similar to what you can do with numbers or other objects. A function stored in a variable can just be executed by adding `()` to the end. You can also pass other parameters to the function if you execute them as `(param1, param2, param3)`, for example. In your case `cb` holds a reference to the function so calling it with `(null, user)` executes it and passes these parameters.

Comment: @VLAZ - thank you! That was very helpful and provides me with the right type of information I need to investigate the 'theory' further to understand it. Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this comment is the answer to this question, I will just put it as answer

Functions are first class members in JavaScript, so they can be assigned to variables, passed as parameters of other functions and returned from functions, too. That's similar to what you can do with numbers or other objects. 
 A function stored in a variable can just be executed by adding () to the end. You can also pass other parameters to the function if you execute them as (param1, param2, param3), for example. In your case cb holds a reference to the function so calling it with (null, user) executes it and passes these parameters

Credits to : [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz)